# I'd like to document c++ code in Markdown. Whenever I have <(char) it disappears

Tags: markdown

If I place < in markdown it is interpreted as something perhaps html tag?
The markdown output disappears.  I'm using stackedit.io

Comment: You need to mark it as code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [< has special meaning in markdown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635226/has-special-meaning-in-markdown)